# Will 2 heavy, simultaneous IO operations result in fragmentation?

Tags: xfs, fragmentation

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 to run a web/DB server.

Disks are in a RAID6 set, using XFS. I'm somewhat new to XFS.

Suppose I have 2 heavy IO operations. In my example:

- Reindexing a 400 GB database.
- Copying over a 500 GB backup, consisting of 5000 files.

Because both are writing to the disk simultaneously, is there any risk of fragmentation that could affect performance?

(I could run `xfs_fsr` to defrag but I'm curious since that takes time/load on large live data sets.)

Details for those who asked:
This is on an EC2 server, using ephemeral storage (I know, use with caution). I mount using:
`sudo mount -t xfs -o noatime /dev/vg0/ephemeral /ephemeral`

Here is my `xfs_info`:

`meta-data=/dev/mapper/vg0-ephemeral isize=256    agcount=32, agsize=32526464 blks
         =                       sectsz=512   attr=2
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=1040846848, imaxpct=5
         =                       sunit=128    swidth=768 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=508232, version=2
         =                       sectsz=512   sunit=8 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your XFS configuration. If you have some level of preallocation set on your filesystem, the impact of fragmentation will be lower than without.

See: [Why are my XFS filesystems suddenly consuming more space and full of sparse files?](https://serverfault.com/questions/406069/why-are-my-xfs-filesystems-suddenly-consuming-more-space-and-full-of-sparse-file/406070#406070)

Can you post the `xfs_info` for your filesystem and the output of `/etc/fstab`?